# building a setter with generic list

Tags: java

Currentlly I am busy with a small java program which is using generic lists. I wanted to use a setter now (getter is ready). But the problem is that I am not able to do it as usually:

```
public void setInventar(Item x) {
    inventar.insert(Item x) = x;
}
```

Problem: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

my getter looks like that:

```
public List<Item> getInventar() {
    return inventar;
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the setter is just a method, which sets variable and is not doing something with the existing one, so in your case setter would be something like:

```
public void setInventar(List<Item> inventar) {
    this.inventar = inventar;
}
```

But if you want to add elements to the existing list (is it what you want?) you may do something like:

```
public void addToInventar(Item x) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(inventar);
    inventar.add(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for letting us know about `Objects.requireNonNull();`.

Comment: @shekharsuman it'll be also quite useful to see it's full signature, since this method is extremely useful in constructors, where you can write smth like `this.x = Object.requireNonNull(x);`

Comment: Except in the example inventar is not a parameter to addToInventar() which makes the use of requireNonNull() a bit unconventional.

Comment: Yes, the second thing is what I wanted. But you used add(x), I could use my insert method as well, couldn't I?:

   <code> public Inventar insert(Item x) {
        if (isEmpty() || x.compareTo(firstItem()) <= 0) {
            Inventar l = new Inventar();
            l.item = x;
            l.next = next;
            next = l;
            return this;
        }
        return next.insert(x);
    } </code>

Comment: @kellerprogger It all depends on what you want to achieve, it seems to me, that you should reformulate your request.

Comment: @ci_ I'm not sure, if it's just for parameters. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) doesn't states it as so. **UPD**Oops, I should have read it more careful.